# React + Typescript: How to handle events

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How should events be handled with React and Typescript? I can't seem to get the typings correct to have a generic input handler like the React docs do in regular JS.

```
state = {
  userId: '',
  amount: undefined,
  type: 'CREDIT',
  note: '',
};

handleChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

As you can see I have a mix of state keys and value types and since the event type is not tied down to be any of those, then the variable key `[event.target.name]` fails with the error...

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State | Pick<State, "type" | "userId" | "amount" | "note">...
```

What is the best way to get around this other than making a special event handler for every field?

Comment: I would highly recommend to have a different handler for each field. What you're doing is in contrast with the most basic idea of Typescript.

Comment: The basic idea of typescript is to provide type safety. I am asking if there is a way to handle multiple fields based on enums or types that will provide type safety while also condensing some code at the same time

Comment: Using one handler for all fields is an anti-pattern in Typescript, because it would force you to manually provide the type every time you use the function, which is even more error-prone than not having types at all.